# plantuml : grouping sequence makes actor appears

Tags: plantuml

I am trying to make a plantuml diagram grouping some activation with notes on groups.
It looks like this :

```
actor User as U
box SBCP
participant "First" as F
participant "Second" as S

U -> F  : "start"

group firstgroup
    note over firstgroup
        a first  note
    end note
    F -> S ++ : first 
    S -> F  -- : end first 
end group

group secondgroup
    note over secondgroup
        a second note
    end note
    F -> S ++ : second 
    S -> F  -- : end second 
end group
```

It works great except it generates strange pseudo actors   :

[image]

Is it possible to remove this lifeline ?

[image]

to get something like (edited with paint.net) :

[image]

Thanks ,

Olivier

Comment: What do you mean with "remove this actors"? Do you mean remove the image but leave the text "User"  or ...

Comment: I mean removing the "firstgroup" and "secondgroup" actors lifline.... they do not really exist and clutter the diagram. they appear as soon as I add a note over the 2 groups "firstgroup" and "secondgroup". But I need this note to add usefull information. So is it possible to keep the notes AND remove the lifelines ?

Comment: Would something like `alt firstgroup a first note\nnext line

    F -> S ++ : first 
    S -> F  -- : end first 
end` be acceptable instead of `group`?

Comment: Thanks for you solution @albert. I would rather stay with a clasic note as we use to have in UML diagrams. They offer much more clarity. see http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/PP31YiCW48RlFiMFrv0No649k-1vGNBQxS4cjWYf1fr07h_Z9BI4pa4Olj__4_j2BjFwc9KRAMKCnMUuWa5TqmRx_VEh5Ww4CImk4hG9kP2k2NC6reyfJaAiKWFQBnYWWnQ1LZnmC-7lLXlkEQrBX__e83jY8dzHWAaNBPe6tK7gCB17OzioyN7QAOEwlCgBl4BQuR1lqisgw3V27A9uS5OTIG6VgZSLMSy7_zWJ for the final rendering of your solution

Comment: I would think that it would be nice to have the classic note for groups too, but I didn't find anything, so hence my workaround. Maybe also post in the pantuml forum (https://forum.plantuml.net/questions).

Answer (score 2):

After asking plantuml forum the right workaround is to add the note on participand not group :

```
@startuml
actor User as U
box SBCP
participant "First" as F
participant "Second" as S

U -> F  : "start"

group firstgroup 
    F -> S ++ : first 
    S -> F  -- : end first 
' add the note to the right
note right: a note 
end group

group secondgroup
    F -> S ++ : second 
' add the note to the right
note right: another note
    S -> F  -- : end second 

end group
@enduml
```

the final result is
[image]